# EasyNetQ/RabbitMQ - Publishing a message based on topic

Tags: c#, rabbitmq, easynetq

I have created a subscriber in EasyNetQ/RabbitMQ with a topic. I think I have atleast because I can see that there is a binding under a queue name. It looks like the following :

[image]

The Queue name itself is a random GUID. But I don't think this matters.

However when I try and publish a message via EasyNetQ like so :

```
await _bus.PublishAsync(new Message<byte[]>(memoryStream.ToArray()), "QueueCallback");
```

The message never gets published onto the above queue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Worked this out.

I was publishing inside a message wrapper, however I was subscribing as a byte array only. Even if the routing key is the same, if the object type is not an exact match it will never be routed.